# Getting TypeError while trying to call a Server URL in Mocha test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to unit test an API which does registration of a user. But  getting a,

```
 TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
```

This is my code block,

```
describe("User registration unit test", ()=>{
  it("The users should be able to register with proper credentials", ()=>{
    return chai.request(testServer)
              .post("/api/auth/register")
              .set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded")
              .send({
                "name": "Jithin333",
                "email": "jtihin324@gmail.com",
                "password": "Jithin12!",
                "role": "user"
              }).then((res)=> {
                expect(res).to.have.status(201);
                done();
              })
  });
});
```

Comment: can you also post response your api is giving ?

Comment: My api should give a 201 with response "User created successfully"

Comment: I understand what your API should give, here I am asking for actual response it is giving.

Comment: TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
      at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:481:11)
      at Test.Request._end (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:804:84)
      at Test.Request.end (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:777:15)
      at Context.it (test/c.userRegister.js:20:18)

Comment: this error is **not** due to mocha test case, it appears to be coming from your user signup service. Have a look into it instead (probably during usage of `superagent` library).

Comment: Not using superagent for anything

Comment: Can you please share you api code.

Comment: Sorry I will not be able to do that. API is working fine, Its the test which is failing

Comment: ok.I think you should pass a string to send not an object. Try JSON.stringifying the object before passing it to send.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass a string to send not an object. Try JSON.stringifying the object before passing it to send. Like below.

```
describe("User registration unit test", ()=>{
  it("The users should be able to register with proper credentials", ()=>{
    return chai.request(testServer)
              .post("/api/auth/register")
              .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
              .send({
                "name": "Jithin333",
                "email": "jtihin324@gmail.com",
                "password": "Jithin12!",
                "role": "user"
              }).then((res)=> {
                expect(res).to.have.status(201);
              });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi found the answer add JSON.stringify and remove done() should work

```
 it("The users should be able to register with proper credentials", ()=>{
    return chai.request(testServer)
              .post("/api/auth/register")
              .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
              .send(JSON.stringify({
                "name": "Jithin",
                "email": "jtihindr1@gmail.com",
                "password": "Jithin12!",
                "role": "user"
              })).then((res)=> {
                expect(res).to.have.status(201);
      });
```